# Restoring MetaMask wallet on new laptop

Tags: metamask, recovery, meta-data

I bought a new laptop and was intending to install Metamask on it. Some background, I have my 12-seed recovery phrase, I know my password, and have ever only had 1 account ever. When installing I use the import function with my seed phrase but after install I get a different address; (again only seed phrase ever) however, when i view in “portfolio view” the Dapp, I can see my assets. Does this prove I’m using seed phrase correctly?  Is there a way to correct this? so I can transfer funds?

Thank you in advance,
J.